# Обновление базы данных с сервера

Tags: android, sqlite

Добрый день.  У меня имеется MySQL база на сервере, там хранятся (ну или будет храниться) информация об объектах. Забирать данные думаю через запрос на сервер и получения ответа в JSON формате. В андроиде уже парсить и вставлять в базу. Но тут сталкиваюсь с проблемой. База будет "живой" и часто обновляться.

Новые записи вытащить будет не проблема. А как отслеживать удаленные? не закачивать же базу полностью из-за пары удаленных объектов?

Все что в голову пришло это добавить на сервере таблицу, в которой будет храниться ID удаленного объекта и дата удаления. И при запросе обновлений передавать дату последнего апдейта и выбирать все удаления начиная с этой даты.  Но вот верное ли это решение, кто делал подобное, поделитесь опытом. Может толковые статьи знаете на эту тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Применяемое решение достаточно сильно будут зависит от характера и динамики изменения информации. У Вас может получится так что информация об удалённых объектах будет больше информации об самих объектах. Если Вам не нужен лог, то это бессмысленный избыток.

В Вашем случае я бы попробовал такой метод:

1. Получаем ид всех объектов в локальной базе
2. Отправляем их на сервер
3. На сервере, определяем какие из эти ид удалённые (которых нету в серверной бд)
4. Формируем ответ на удаление объектов
5. Формируем ответ с новыми объектами.

Comment: Очень интересная идея, она мне однозначно больше нравится чем моя.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно физически вообще удалять что-либо на сервере. Добавьте столбец-флаг `active` и помечайте с помощью него "удалённые" записи.

Таким образом легко будет выдавать наружу все изменения БД.

Answer (score 0):

Да хорошо оставлять удаленные записи в таблице, только надо создать колонку не флаг удаления, а дата - время удаления и очень старые записи удалять совсем по мере ненадобности, иначе таблица разрастается со временем.